# VBA very slow after splitting Access DB (local PC, not network)

Tags: vba, ms-access

After splitting my Access DB I have found that VBA code run in MS Project (called from within Access) has slowed down significantly (by a factor of about 6).

I am using MS Access 2016 and Project 2016, both on my local PC with no network traffic.

The VBA code in MS Project does a series of lookups against the Access database and it is these procedures that are running slowly.  I would have expected a slowdown if my Access Backend was on a corporate network, but am surprised to see a slowdown when both back end and front end and MS Project are all local.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Eric

Comment: There is no reason why It will be slow if both back end and front end are local. Why don't you try to improve tables/queries by adding index for example. Index can drastically improve performance.

Comment: Please describe your *local* drive. Does BE and FE reside in same directory? What type of folder: C drive, external hard drive, thumb drive, internet folder (i.e., Dropbox, OneDrive, GoogleDrive)? Low hard disk space? Need of defragmentation? Other diagnostic measures?

Comment: Not sure of MS Project but how is BE connection made? ODBC or OLEDB drivers? Did *anything* else change with split? CPUs, workstations, office versions, etc.?  Think carefully as even very minor changes can be the issue

Comment: @Parfait BE and FE are made using access. Basically you can choose to separate the Data Objects (Tables, Queries...) and Interface Objects (Forms, Reports...)

Comment: I will explore the indexing, thanks for the suggestion.  FYI both BE and FE reside in the same folder on my laptop's hard drive.  I made NO other changes other than splitting the DB.  I then ran the macro in Access that opens MS Project, recreates a master plan and populates various MSP fields with data from Access.  What previously took 12 seconds now takes 75 seconds.  And this is with test data.  With the full data set I would expect it to increase from 8 minutes to about 90 minutes, which is unacceptable.  In the meantime I am exploring more efficient ways of getting data from Access.

Comment: Welcome! I posted an answer that I think might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the slowdown you are experiencing is the backend file repeatedly opening and closing when it is being accessed by the frontend. The accepted solution is to open a persistent link between the frontend and the backend. This way the backend file will stay open for as long as a frontend is open.

To set this up, you will need to create an empty table in the backend that isn't used anywhere else in the project. I'll call it `tblKeepOpen`

Sample code: (called in the `AutoExec` macro)

```
Public Sub KeepBackendLinkOpen() 
    Static rsOpen As DAO.Recordset ' Static makes the Recordset reference persist
    Set rsOpen = CurrentDb.OpenRecordSet("SELECT * FROM tblKeepOpen", dbOpenSnapshot)
End Sub
```

This reference will persist until the VBA interpreter crashes or loses state. You can reload the link by running `KeepBackendLinkOpen` from the Immediate window, or running `AutoExec` again.

Some people like to manage persistent links in a hidden form. Your choice.

PS -- there are lots of examples on the internet on how to do this, but I couldn't find any with a nice simple example.

Comment: Kismert, sorry for the delayed response.  I realised that in my application splitting was not necessary and so I stopped looking for a solution, and forgot to check back here.  However I will mark your response as an answer as it certainly looks like a good one and you deserve the credit for providing it.  Thanks again